# Vector function contained in a plane

Tags: vectors, plane-curves

Show that the particle represented by $\vec{r(t)} = \langle t^2+1, -2t+4, 4t^2+2t-3\rangle$ is contained in the plane $\pi : ax+by+cz = d$ $\forall$ $t$

I arrived at $a(t^2+1) + b(-2t+4) + c(4t^2+2t-3) = 0$ from the thought that $\vec{r(t)}$ must be orthogonal to $\vec{n}$ $\forall$ $t$ and then taking the dot product. But I can't find values for $a,b,c$ for which the expression is always $0$.

Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 2):

you may just substitute the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of  $\vec{r(t)}$ into the equation of the plane

rewriting your equation (with $d$ included),  arranged in powers of $t$
$$
(a+4c)t^2 +2(c-b)t +(a+4b-3c-d)=0
$$
this expression must be identically zero, so each coefficient vanishes.
so $b=c$,$a=-4c$, $d=-3c$ and the plane is (cancelling $c$)
$$
-4x+y+z=-3
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is contained in the plane $\pi$, it must be the case that $\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}$ (not $\mathbf{r}(t)$ as you suggested) is 
orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane $\mathbf{n} = (a, b , c)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0 \Rightarrow a(2t) + b(-2)+c(8t+2) = 0
\end{align*}
$$

By inspection, this is true when $a = -4, b = 1, c = 1$. Now we need to solve for $d$. For $t=0$, the corresponding point on the path $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is $(1,4,-3)$; plugging this into the equation for $\pi$ yields $d = -3$. Therefore, $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is contained in the plane $\pi: -4x + y + z = -3$.

Comment: Why must it be the case that the derivative is orthogonal?

Comment: @John $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a position vector that gives the location of points on the path of the particle relative to the origin of the coordinate system. $\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}$ gives the (unnormalized) tangent vectors to the path of the particle. Intuitively, if the path lies in the plane $\pi$, so must all of these tangent vectors.